# compiling a project with multiple versions of a dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My application uses an old google play version that contains a class that I need,
unfortunately it's not possible to upgrade right now (due to time limitations)

A library that my application depends on, requires a newer version of google play, that does not longer hold that class.

My question is:
Is there a way to compile the library with a newer version, while compiling my application with the older one?
the current behaviour by gradle is to compile both of them with the newer google play version.

Comment: nope. both libraries will include classes from the same package with the same name, but with different content. the only way would be to take the class you still need (with its own dependencies) and move it to another package. I guess you can try to decompile it, move it, and recompile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to force use your `google play` version for library by [excluding transitive dependency](https://github.com/withmate/withmate_destory/blob/54b58db02dd6a763304042e1dc0eb0a3a2612c4d/plugins/hibernate-2.2.3/dependencies.groovy#L16).

But is might not work. If so you can use hack way - changes package names in your version of google play as well use these "changed" classes in your app.